# IndexError with object detection labels

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, index-error, openvino

I detec objects from a video with [this](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_models_intel_person_vehicle_bike_detection_crossroad_0078_description_person_vehicle_bike_detection_crossroad_0078.html) model. The model detects three classes: bicycles, cars and persons. I only want cars and persons and thats's what I get until there are bikes in the picture. Then I get an error `IndexError: list out of range`.

This is my code:

```
CLASSES = ["bicycle", "car", "person"]

for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    if confidence > 0.4:
       idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
       if CLASSES[idx] == "person" or CLASSES[idx] == "car":
          print("CLASSES[idx]: ", CLASSES[idx])
```

The error points to the line: `if CLASSES[idx] == "person" or CLASSES[idx] == "car":`. I already tried to check for other indexes (bicycle) like this:

```
if CLASSES[idx] == "person" or CLASSES[idx] == "car":
    print("CLASSES[idx]: ", CLASSES[idx])

else:
    print("Not a car/person")
    continue
```

The error was still the same and the else was never executed. Any advices what is wrong here are welcome.

Edit. I did some logging and found out that the index is sometimes 3 and that's why the script fails. The models documents says:

```
The net outputs blob with shape: [1, 1, N, 7], where N is the number of detected bounding boxes. Each detection has the format [image_id, label, conf, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max], where:

image_id - ID of the image in the batch
label - predicted class ID
conf - confidence for the predicted class
(x_min, y_min) - coordinates of the top left bounding box corner
(x_max, y_max) - coordinates of the bottom right bounding box corner.
```

So am I going through the detections in a wrong way?

This is how I get the detections:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(
    "models/person-vehicle-bike-detection-crossroad-0078.xml",
    "models/person-vehicle-bike-detection-crossroad-0078.bin")

detections = net.forward()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using OpenVINO pre-trained model, I suggest you try out this sample application: [Pedestrian Tracker Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.2/omz_demos_pedestrian_tracker_demo_README.html)

You should get something like the attached photo. I had used the same model as you are using, person-vehicle-bike-detection-crossroad-0078 with person-reidentification-retail-0277

Once you get it done, try to study the code and implement your own accordingly.

[image]